# Как совместить Python программу и telegram bot?

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, telegram-bot

Есть программа с PyQt5 интерфейсом, хочу добавить в неё ещё телеграмм бота, чтобы приходящие в него сообщения могли выполнять в ней определенные задачи. Пытался через Thread(код ниже), но выбивало с ошибкой: ValueError: signal only works in main thread.

```
class QueenBot(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
        updater = Updater(token='mytoken')
        dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

        def startCommand(bot, update):
            bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='Стартуем')

        def textMessage(bot, update):
            messageText = str(update.message.text)

        start_command_handler = CommandHandler('start', startCommand)
        text_message_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, textMessage)
        dispatcher.add_handler(start_command_handler)
        dispatcher.add_handler(text_message_handler)
        updater.start_polling(clean=True)
        updater.idle()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить конструкцию

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    updater.start_polling(clean=True)
    updater.idle()
```

Такое может быть, из-за того что запуск бота производится из класса, а должен производиться из мэйна. Телеграм-бот - по сути сервер

Comment: Никаких изменений не дало. Зато отлично сработало удаление последней строки: updater.idle(). Это чем нибудь чревато или можно так оставить, раз работает на ура?

Comment: Раз работает можно и оставить :D